# Browser complains about a javascript const value being not defined

Tags: javascript, session

I'm having a project, where I'm using a script to save a logged in user to the session and one to get the user from the session, but if the user isn't logged in, it will return undefined.
So I'm making a const of the user from the function and using an if statement to check if the user is undefined.
But there comes an error in the if statement, where the browser tells me the user is not defined, but that is the whole idea that it is not.

```
const user = getUser();
if (user !== undefined)
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: const user = getUser(); is a call to a Function and that function does not exist, at least in the pasted snippet. undefined and not defined are different

Comment: Is that really the code? I suspect there's a scope problem, and you haven't shown enough of the code to see it.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: It's not the whole code, just an example. But from what @grisuu describes, it makes sense now that undefined and not defined is different. I will look into that.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: you will get `is not defined` when trying to use a variable not defined at all. A variable is a function name also. But in that code you showed, such an error could come only from calling `getUser()` as something that was not defined because the `user` var is defined in the moment you did `const user`